# sitecore: multi-lingual site

Tags: sitecore

I'm working on a site that will support several languages. I create a template and a content item. Then I fill in the fields for language-specific versions of a content item. Thats OK.

I want to translate labels that go through the whole application. 
Let it be "More" label. I thought it is something about Dictionary and usage of Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.Text("More") but it doesn't work for pages with non-default language(provided I created a language-specific version of a dictionary item).

What is the correct solution?

Answer (score 1):

> but it doesn't work for pages with non-default language(provided I created a language-specific version of a dictionary item)

Vitaliy,

Leveraging dictionary for this purpose is a proper way of doing it.

The Text method of Sitecore.Globalization.Translate class is supposed to respect the context language, so that should work.

```cs
public static string Text(string key)
{
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull(key, "key");
    return TextByLanguage(key, Context.Language);
}
```

Please file a ticket with tech support if that does not work for you.