# usage of dictionary for sitecore multilingual site

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Previously I had my website in English language. Now there are request to create website in 2 other languages German and French.

I created items in necessary languages. I want to translate labels like first name, last name etc that go through the whole application, so i used dictionary with `"Key -> FirstName"` and `"Phrase First Name"`. Created dictionary items in English,French and German.
In code I made below changes

```csharp
<h4><% Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.Text("FirstName");%></h4>
```

But I'm unable to see First Name render on the page. Is there any other settings I need to make. Please advice.

Comment: Just to confirm:

Are you using <%= Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.Text("FirstName");%> with the "=" after the %?

Comment: I'm trying to understand your question; have you created an Item with a single Field of Dictionary type and have key value pairs for each translation?

Comment: Hi..it was a typo..had used as <%= Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.Text("FirstName")%></h4>..Yes I have created single dictionary item and have key value pair for languages

Comment: Is everything published? Including the new /system/languages items you created.

Comment: Yes everthing is published. I manually checked in Web database

Comment: Which version of Sitecore you using? Where in the content tree did you create the dictionary items? Can you confirm your key is `Firstname` since you call `Translate.Text("FirstName")` with a capital "N" you should make sure the case matches.

Comment: You can check if your phrase exists in in a dictionary.dat file in the application's /temp/ folder. Besides if it is CD system, it may not know to refresh cache after item was published.

Comment: This is exactly how I handle multiple languages for my site.  You're doing it correctly.  Just make sure you are publishing the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments you may find the answer you are looking for in this question

[sitecore: multi-lingual site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672609/sitecore-multi-lingual-site)

It does outline you may need to contact support if the solution doesn't work for you, but it may be resolved in a version later than Sitecore 6

Comment: Thanks will report it..also have one more issue..how do I provide localised text for say a <asp:label> text field..I dont want it from code behind, I need to put translation in .aspx page

Comment: Usually for this type of task I use a different approach and utilise Sitecore's (<sc:Text>) controls instead of the default asp ones (<asp:Label>). The approach also requires the text to have it's own field on an Sitecore Item. The Item itself is bound to the sc:Text in the code behind but is possible to do it on the front end. When the Language context is changed the value changes to the correct language version (providing it exists and is published)